# Not able to display PDF on IE11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, pdf

**Requirement**:

Get the pdf in the form of arrayBuffer from the server, and display the pdf with in the angular app as an overlay.

**Approach**:

I am getting the pdf file as arrayBuffer from the service. I am  creating a blob out of it by using

```
let file = new Blob([data.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
```

Now I am creating the object Url by using

```
let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

assigned this url to the scope, so that it will become available to the template

```
this.pdf.url = this.$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
```

In the template I added an iFrame

```
<iframe ng-src="{{brief.pdf.url}}" style="width:100%;height:600px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
    <p>It appears your web browser doesn't support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

This works fine in Chrome and FF but doesn't work in IE11
In Chrome and FF the blob url formed is

> blob:http%3A//localhost%3A81/0dceebf5-9d38-4366-8f65-ad12616533b4

but in IE11 the url formed is

> blob:0dceebf5-9d38-4366-8f65-ad12616533b4

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Did u find a solution for this?

Comment: No. I forced downloaded the PDF for IE

Comment: I am also stuck with same issue in angular 4 , can you give me some idea ?

Comment: @Ashitoshbirajdar Force download the pdf, there is no other way out.